# How to allow someone else to send emails in my name?

Tags: webapp-rec

I want to give another person the ability to send emails in my name. This person should be able to send mail using my email address, but not be able to read my email. I use Gmail, but am willing to try others.

Does anybody know a web app or application that can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gmail will be perfect for that.

In his Gmail account, tell him to follow the following steps:

1. Sign in to Gmail.
2. Click Settings and select the Accounts and Import tab.
3. Under Send mail as, click Add another email address.
4. In the 'Email address' field, enter the address from which he will be sending emails (your address)
5. Click Next Step >> and then click Send Verification. Gmail will send a verification message to your email address to confirm that he can use it.

Then you will receive the email verification, you just have to approve it.

**Warning:** Be careful though, I don't think you can remove this privilege from his accounts yourself or force him to remove your email address later on.

[Source](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=22370)

Comment: I actually set up a secondary email account, which's password I can share. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If they use Gmail as well and you have access to their computer/account you can enter your E-Mail address as a custom "From" address. See [`Adding a custom 'From' address`](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370) for details.